# How to change shape in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I would like to take any shape, and drag its edges wherever I want, distorting the image in the process. How do I achieve this ?
Perspective isn't what I am looking for, nor is Filters>Distortions>Curves.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the [Cage tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-cage.html), once you have put nodes around the shape.

Comment: I did try to use it and it seems to be the right tool for free transformation as I desire, however it leaves weird artifacts behind, as if the image is being redrawn above the original. As an example, dragging the corner of a square inwards leaves behind a piece of the original corner. How do I avoid this behaviour ?

Comment: Did you try the "fill original position" option?

Comment: Ah, that is indeed way better. I'll mark this as the answer, since it's as close to what I am trying to achieve as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the Unified Transform Tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

In the toolbox it looks like this:  [image]

It's a multi-functional transform tool. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag an edge handle to distort the image, squishing or stretching it. Moving the edge without <kbd>Shift</kbd> resales proportionally. The corner handles can distort like perspective, and the white diamond handles are for skewing.

[image]

Comment: With this, dragging a corner inward provokes a deformation on the opposite side of the image, as if the image is being rotated along an axis in 3D. I would need for the image to only get "squished" on the corner I'm dragging.

Comment: @oui - so essentially you are looking for some kind of non-uniform deformation. This isn't really possible in raster image editors as far as I know.  If you had a vector shape, then it could be done. But GIMP isn't a vector image editor.